# Which one is greater?

Tags: inequality, tetration

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, let $x\diamond 1=x$ and $x\diamond (n+1) = x^{x\diamond n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For example, $2\diamond 3 = 2^{2^2}=16$.

If $t$ be an unique positive real number such that $t^t = 10^{10^{10}}$, 
I get $10^{10}>t$.

If $k$ be an unique positive real number such that $k\diamond 50 = 10\diamond 51$,

and $s$ be an unique positive real number such that $s\diamond 51 = 10\diamond 52$.

Is it true that $k>s$ ?

Comment: A more common way to express this is [up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) so your $\diamond$ is $\uparrow$

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation.  It would be 

$$2 \uparrow \uparrow 3 = 2^{2^2} = ^{3}2 = 16$$

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,
$$k>s\iff k\diamond 51>s\diamond 51\iff k^{k\,\diamond\,50}>10\diamond 52\iff k^{10\,\diamond\,51}>10^{10\,\diamond\,51}\iff k>10$$
(assuming $k,s>1$). Now note that
$$k\diamond50>10\diamond50\implies k>10.$$